# Do I chill mead?

Tags: alcohol, wine, drinks, chilling

I've just bought a bottle of mead for the first time - do I need to chill it before drinking, like a white wine, or let it breathe before drinking, like a red wine?

Comment: You have made an excellent choice! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often referred to as "Honey Wine", mead is an alcohol made from fermentation of honey. The temperature of mead you want to drink is really variable. If your mead is lighter and dry, it is better to be chilled like white wines whereas the stronger ones can be served at any temperature. I loved it to be chilled.